# Why can't a previously assigned variable be used while defining a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, typeerror

Below is the python code that I am trying to use to run a function.

```
def list_benefits():
    return "More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code 
    `reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"`


def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!" %benefit


def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    for benefi in list_of_benefits:
        print(build_sentence(benefi))


name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

I don't understand why do we need to have the variable 'list_of_benefits' and why can't we directly use 'list_benefits' in the last function. The above code runs well, but if I remove 'list_of_benefits' from everywhere, I get the below error -

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: You have to do `list_benefits()` not `list_benefits`, mind the parentheses, that is how you *call* a function, otherwise, you are just referencing the function object itself.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. You can directly use list_benefits() as the for loop target.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list_benefits() in the loop directly. Check out the below code:

```
def list_benefits():
    return "More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code","reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"

def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!" %benefit

def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    for benefi in list_benefits():
        print(build_sentence(benefi))

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

It worked fine for me. Output:

```
More organized code is a benefit of functions!
More readable code is a benefit of functions!
Easier code is a benefit of functions!
reuse is a benefit of functions!
Allowing programmers to share and connect code together is a benefit of functions!
```

Please not if you want do this (and I believe most probably you ran into error trying this):

```
for benefi in list_benefits:
```

Its not gonna work for you because in such case list_benifits becomes a variable not a function. So it will generate an error.